# Operator font with lualatex not changing correctly

Tags: fonts, luatex, math-operators, font-encodings

I'm using `newpx` as my document font. However I'm having some problems when compiling with `lualatex` because the font of math operators does not change to `newpx` and Computer Modern is shown instead.

Desired output: (compiled using `pdflatex`)

[image: Desired output]

Actual output when using `lualatex`:
[image: Actual output]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[size=a4, 12pt]{scrartcl}

% Fonts
\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}
\usepackage{FiraSans}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% Math
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{faktor}

\begin{document}

This is an example. \[\faktor{G}{\operatorname{Ker}(f)} \cong \operatorname{Im}(f).\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't use \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} and newpxtext with lualatex.

Comment: In `unicode-math`, Asana Math is a good replacement for `newtxmath`, and `newpxtext` is a direct clone of Palatino. So is TeX Gyre Pagella.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use T1 encoding and newpxtext math with luatex.

You can do something like this:

```
\documentclass[size=a4, 12pt]{scrartcl}

% Math
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{faktor}

% Fonts
\usepackage{newpxmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}

\DeclareSymbolFont{operators}{TU}{\rmdefault}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{operators}{bold}{TU}{\rmdefault}{b}{n}

\usepackage{FiraSans}

\begin{document}

This is an example. \[\faktor{G}{\operatorname{Ker}(f)} \cong \operatorname{Im}(f).\]

\end{document}
```

[image]